# string slicing in php or mysql substring_index

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

Output of following query has to be sliced.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subject.id, '-', subject.en_title ORDER BY subject.id) AS sub,
```

Output is

```
3-Math
4-Science
```

I am Using PHP `substr`

```
$sub=substr(strstr($row['sub'], '-'), 1);
```

so result would be

```
Math
Science
```

But It would be better, if it can be sliced in mysql, because I think it reduces php code and less data fetched from database.
So I have tried **SUBSTRING_INDEX**

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subject.id, '-', subject.en_title ORDER BY subject.id), '-', -1) AS sub,
```

But I get only one row

```
Science
```

Here, does `SUBSTRING_INDEX` affect to select row ? if not how can I fetch expected output

Comment: Please show the entire SELECT function.

Comment: so you want to concat the field subject.en_title and strip it off again in the same query? Why not directly use this field?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310336/2469308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `CONCAT` `subject.id`. You can directly use `DISTINCT` clause on `subject.en_title`. Use the following expression instead:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subject.en_title ORDER BY subject.id) AS sub
```

Comment: bracket after SUBSTR is not closing, where to put it's closing bracket,

Comment: @AnandHmt check the edited answer. Please confirm if it works or not ?

Comment: Thanks - but I get Partial result, I got `Math`, `4-Science`, How can I solve this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179967/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-anandhmt).

Answer (score 0):

You should try using REPLACE

```
SELECT
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subject.id, '-', subject.en_title ORDER BY subject.id), '-', 1) AS sub
```

I would also put the DISTINCT outside of the GROUP_CONCAT, and properly use GROUP BY

Comment: I got result `31Math`, `41Science`. It is replacing `-` to `1`, I need to remove string before -, so result would be `Math`, `Science`

Comment: Which is what you need?

Comment: I need to remove string before the special characters `-`, What I am getting result is `3-Math`, but I need only `Math` removing the part from special characters `-`

Comment: Then why do you SELECT the field subject.id in the 1st place ? if you need the DISTINCT id, then you should re-edit your query, please add to the question, I'll be able to improve my answer

Comment: If I don't include `DISTINCT subject.id` in first place, `subject.title` would be repeat, if there are same `subject.title`, so to prevent repeating, I am assigning `DISTINCT.id`